# I have to make a car dealership program, but I dont know how to read from a file

Tags: c++

So the problem is that at option 6 of the switch.
When I need to load a file, currently it just reads the file and displays it's content, but I need to load the .txt file as in option 3, to create different things on the class for it to be different cars.

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

class Car
{
private:
    string name;
    string color;
    double price;

public:
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /*
    * Constructor/Destructor
    *
    * Handles creation and deletion of Car objects.
    *
    * Parameter: name_in
    *       The name of a new car
    * Parameter: color_in
    *       The color of a new car
    * Parameter: price_in
    *       The price of a new car
    */
    Car(string name_in, string color_in, double price_in);
    virtual ~Car();
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /*
    * getName
    *
    * Returns the name of the car.
    *
    * Return:
    *       The name of the car
    */
    string getName();
    /*
    * getColor
    *
    * Returns the color of the car.
    *
    * Return:
    *       The color of the car
    */
    string getColor();
    /*
    * getPrice
    *
    * Returns the price of the car.
    *
    * Return:
    *       The price of the car
    */
    double getPrice();
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /*
    * paint
    *
    * Paints the car a new color and increases the price by $1,000.
    *
    * Parameter: new_color
    *       The color of paint to be used on the car
    */
    void paint(string new_color);
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /*
    * toString
    *
    * Returns a single string containing useful information about the car.
    *
    * Return:
    *       A data string about this car
    */
    string toString();
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
};


using namespace std;

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Car::Car(string name_in, string color_in, double price_in)
{
    name = name_in;
    color = color_in;
    price = price_in;
}
Car::~Car() {}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
string Car::getName()
{
    return name;
}
string Car::getColor()
{
    return color;
}
double Car::getPrice()
{
    return price;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void Car::paint(string new_color)
{
    color = new_color;
    price += 1000;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
string Car::toString()
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss << "Name: " << name << endl;
    ss << "Color: " << color << endl;
    ss << "Price: $" << price << endl;
    return ss.str();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>


using namespace std;

int fileread(string a){

    string filename;
    string getcontent;
    ifstream name;
    cin >> filename;
    filename.append(".txt");
    name.open(filename.c_str());

    if (!name.is_open()) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (true)
    {
        getline(name, getcontent);
        if (name.eof()) break;
        cout << getcontent << endl;
    }
    name.close();

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int option;
    string name;
    string color;
    double price = 0;
    double balance = 10000;
    vector <Car> cars;

    do
    {
        cout << "Please select an option:" << endl;
        cout << "1 - Show current inventory." << endl;
        cout << "2 - Show current balance." << endl;
        cout << "3 - Buy a car." << endl;
        cout << "4 - Sell a car." << endl;
        cout << "5 - Paint a car." << endl;
        cout << "6 - Load file." << endl;
        cout << "7 - Save file." << endl;
        cout << "8 - Quit program." << endl;
        cout << "\n";

        cin >> option;

        if (option == 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < cars.size(); i++)
            {
                cout << cars[i].toString() <<"\n";
            }
        }
        if (option == 2)
        {
            cout << "$" << balance << endl;
        }
        if (option == 3)
        {
            cout << "Please enter the name, color, and price of the car you would like to buy." << endl;
            cin >> name;
            cin >> color;
            cin >> price;
            Car newcar(name, color, price);

            if (price <= balance)
            {
                cars.push_back(newcar);
                cout << "Car has been purchased." << endl;
                balance = balance - price;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "You cannot afford that car." << endl;
                option = 0;
            }
        }
        if (option == 4)
        {
            cout << "Please enter the name of the car you want to sell." << endl;
            cin >> name;
            bool found = true;

            for (int j = 0; j < cars.size(); j++)
            {
                if (cars[j].getName() == name)
                {
                    found = false;
                    price = cars[j].getPrice();
                    cars.erase(cars.begin() + j);
                    cout << "You have sold the " << name << endl;
                    balance = balance + price;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "You don't own that car." << endl;
                }
            }
        }
        if (option == 5)
        {
            cout << "Please enter the name of the car you want to paint." << endl;
            cin >> name;
            bool found = true;

            for (int j = 0; j < cars.size(); j++)
            {
                if (cars[j].getName() == name)
                {
                    found = false;
                    cout << "What color do you want to paint the " << name << "?" << endl;
                    cin >> color;
                    cars[j].paint(color);
                    cout << "You have painted the " << name << " " << color << "." << endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "You don't own that car." << endl;
                }
            }
        }
        if (option == 6)
        {
            string chooseFile;
            cout<<"File name: ";
            fileread(chooseFile);
        }
        if (option == 7)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < cars.size(); i++)
            {
                ofstream fout;
                fout.open("cars3.txt");
                fout << cars[i].toString() << endl;
                fout << "$" << balance << endl;
            }
        }
        if (option == 8)
        {
            exit(0);
        }
        if (option < 0 || option > 8)
        {
            cout << "Please enter a number from 1-8." << endl;
        }

        cout << "\n";
    } while (option < 8 || option > 8);
}
```

This is the code for the program.

This is an example of what I should read from the file:

```
59715.43
Navy White 6972.15
Kidney Red 3971.15
Refried Brown 9999.99
Garbanzo White 975.21
Black Black 7946.85
Edamame Green 555.55
Lima White 5873.15
Pinto Brown 12368.99
```

How should I approach this, and what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please remember the *minimal* part of your [mre].

Comment: Lastly, and to maybe be a little brutal, any decent book, tutorial or class should have information about how to read from or write to files.

Comment: In `if (option == 7)` Don't keep opening the same file inside the loop.

Comment: Replace `while (true)
    {
        getline(name, getcontent);
        if (name.eof()) break;` with `while (getline(name, getcontent)) {`

Comment: `while (option < 8 || option > 8);` is bad use `while (option != 8);` instead. and please don't use if-s as a switch-case

Comment: @BotondHorváth why is `while (option < 8 || option > 8);` bad ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number
Sorry it is not bad as It works fine  but it looks stupid, and easy to make a bug if you have to re-write it eg.: 8 to 9, and it is slower then != too. So it is a bad practice.

Comment: @BotondHorváth I was actually just teasing you because saying "it is bad" alone doesn't help. You can erase the "So it is bad practice" from your last comment and the message of the comment will stay the same. Btw it should not be any slower, unless the compilers optimizations are broken beyond repair

Comment: This case yes it can optimize (gcc optimise if at least -O1 is on) but if it is a function not marked as const it can't. (keep in mind that || is lasy so it isn't allow to ceck both side at the same time)

Comment: @BotondHorvath you are now refering to the case when it is not a matter of optimizations but semantics. When one has other meaning than the other, then only one is correct and should not be replaced with the other for the sake of being faster. But we are going rather offtopic now ;)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1)

[Split](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-split-a-string-in-cc-python-and-java/) the string and then convert it's third

Option 2)

don't use getline. The loop in `fileread` should be:

```
string carName,carColor;
double carPrice;
while (name>>carName>>carColor>>carPrice){ 
    Car c(carName,carColor,setPrice(carPrice);
    //save the car to your vector
}
```

Option 3)

define the >> operator for Car

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Car& c){
    return is>>c.name>>c.color>>c.price;
}
```

and add this as a friend of Car, then by `cin>>c;` or `name>>c;` you can read a car. from stdin or the file.

Also you need to pass the vector of cars to the function by reference, and it doesn't need an unused string parameter.

Note: please don't name a filestramen "name"

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, as I'm quite new to C++, I don't seem to quite get it.
Could you kindly modify the code so I could get an example?
Thanks.

Comment: here is the code. I also fixed option 4 and 5 https://github.com/HoBoIs/Cars/tree/main

Comment: Thank you so much for giving me an example, but it doesn't seem to work...
I run it from main.cpp everything is fine, I go to option 6, type the name of the file, goes back in menu, and when I do option 1, as in to show inventory, nothing is loaded from the file, do you have any idea why that is ?

Comment: Are the file-format name color price;name color price... or there the balance first? If there is balance first uncomment the lines in fileread, as I wrote down in the comment. (also return it)

Comment: The file-format is the one in the original thread, where I gave the example, with balance on the first line, and each model of car with its color and price on lines below that, I uncommented the lines where you placed comments (in option 6 and fileread), I don't get any errors, but after I read using option 6, I press on option 1 (Show Inventory) and it's empty.

Comment: You probably want to ask a new question showing a [mcve] with the input output and expected output. With your minimal example try to reduce as much of the code as you can while retaining a program that someone else can build, test and produce the result you do. Your current code had a lot of parts that are not part of the problem and distract from the problem you want solved. Remember that StackOverflow is not a forum. The main purpose of your question is to help future readers with the same problem.

Comment: @Sorinaqueee I made some changes so it logs the cars it reads. Also it reads the balance (need nothing to uncomment). It should work (look out, you cannot have spaces in the filename also it maybe case sensitive).